Should I list a dual affiliation in publications when incorporating prior independent work into my current full-time research?
I’m currently employed full-time as a researcher, and my institution has asked me to integrate a tool I originally developed during my prior independent consulting/research. The tool was created before my current role and represents substantial groundwork from that time.
Some colleagues suggest I should list both my current institution and my former consulting affiliation in publications to reflect the tool’s origins. Others caution that this could imply I’m actively engaged in multiple roles, which might conflict with my full-time employment status.
Questions:

Is it appropriate to list both affiliations in such cases, and if so, how best to present it?
Are there alternative ways to acknowledge prior independent work without potential conflicts?

Any advice from those who’ve faced similar situations would be very helpful. Thank you!

Where do you want to list both affiliations? You only say [your] institution has asked [you] to integrate a tool, but for what purpose and occasion? Is this about publishing a paper and your tool is part of an experimental setup? Is this about publishing software, and your tool will be part of it? Is this about generally publishing your affiliation, e.g. on a work or private website?

@MisterMiyagi The institution requested that I incorporate a Python library I had developed previously (during independant work), building further capabilities on top of it to meet their project objectives efficiently. The aim is to publish the resulting work in a journal based on the progress achieved during my contract. There are also plans to eventually make a free version of this tool available online.

@MisterMiyagi The dual affiliation is intended specifically for the upcoming publication, for which I am the primary author.

Is your consultancy still active?

I am employee 100% with the institution right now, but aiming at working again as independent after this research contract

If your previous work has already been published, just citing the original publication is enough. If you are publishing it (or using the results in a publication) for the first time, you can consider it as work that started before your current employment. In such a case listing two affiliations is standard practice. A double affiliation does not always mean that you are simultaneously employed by two institutions. It can also be understood as the list of places where you worked during the whole duration of the project, which can last for much longer than a single employment contract. The second affiliation gives credit to the other institution which paid you while you did what has now become an important part of the publication.

If you keep your consultancy active, or expect to return to it in the future, then this is probably something worth doing. But if it is dead and will likely remain so, there is little point in it. Especially for a consultancy of one. You "are" or were that consultancy. Your name is enough.
However, not for ethical or legal reasons, you may want your current employer's explicit permission for such a thing, just to help maintain your position there and their good will.
You can, instead, put in something like an acknowledgement statement that names the consultancy, though if it doesn't have a name independent of your true name it is hardly worth it.  But you could note that package X predates your current affiliation and was developed independly.

"You can, instead, put in something like an acknowledgement statement that names the consultancy": Some formats also allow a notes section which could be used to provide details of a dual affiliation if you want to explain something about it. That might be more suitable than using the acknowledgements. Or you add a footnote.
